# Laravel 8 controller returning Foreach loop error

Tags: php, laravel-8

HI I'm working on a laravel 8 application in which I've added an additional information on my json and trying to return it through the controller. but i'm getting a `foreach() loop requires object|array string given` error. Here's my code for the controller. Please help me understand what's going wrong here.

```
 public function index(Request $request): JsonResponse

{
    $user = Auth()->user();
    $cart = Cart::where('user_id', $user->id)->with('items')->first();

    $fabric_items = json_decode($cart->items,true);

    // dd(gettype($cart->items));
    foreach($fabric_items as $key => $item)
    {
        $sku = explode("-",$item['product_data']['Fabric']);
        $product_image = Products::where('sku','like','%'.$sku[0].'%')->get();
        $fabric_items[$key]['image_url'] = $product_image[0]->image_url;
    }

    $cart->items = json_encode($fabric_items);

    if (!$cart) {
        return $this->returnError(__('You don\'t have any item in the cart'));
    }
    return response()->json(['status' => true, 'data' => $cart]);
}
```

Error:
`{"status":false,"error":"foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given"}`

Comment: It seems `$fabric_items` is a `string`. What is the output of `dd($fabric_items)`? Also, since $cat->items seems to come from a relationship, why do you need to decode it? It should be already iterable (Collection instance)

Comment: please show what `$cart->items` contains

Comment: Can you share how your Cart Model look like

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use json_decode on items which is a relationship, remove the json_decode and loop.

Comment: What should i do then ?

Comment: Just loop through $cart->items,though that depends if $cart->items is a collection.

Comment: @dannyyol instead of using json_decode you can define inside your cart model  protected $casts = ['items' => array]